# BlackBerry - Horizontal Alignment of LabelField in Screen

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, label, text-alignment

I want to add a new LabelField(String label, long style) but if I use Field.FIELD_HCENTER as my style then I get the following alignment.

```
|---- This text is horizontally aligned but in ----|
|---- a block.
```

But what I want is;

```
|---- This text is horizontally aligned and ----|
|------- independently so for each line --------|
```

Is this simple to achieve? I can't find the field constant to get this to work for me.

Thanks in advance,

Gav

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [DrawStyle.HCENTER](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/DrawStyle.html#HCENTER)

[alt text http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/6245/9000.jpg](http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/6245/9000.jpg)

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    String mText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "
            + "consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed adipiscing "
            + "dui quis velit placerat vulputate.";
    LabelField mLabel = new LabelField(mText, DrawStyle.HCENTER);

    public Scr() {
        add(mLabel);
    }
}
```